# Should we change the tag 'Water' to 'Hydration'?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging, tag-synonyms

The [hydration](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hydration) tag already acts as a synonym for [water](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water). I think the water tag should be changed to hydration. Here are the main differences between the two words and why I consider hydration to be a more suitable tag.

Water can be anything to do with drinking, bottles/bladders, rain, puddles and bike corrosion.

Hydration can have any think to do with drinking, bottles/bladders, [sports drinks](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/852/homemade-sports-drinks) and nutrition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're right; I looked at all the [water](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water) questions and indeed they are all pretty much about [hydration](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hydration).

So, I reversed the synonym and renamed the tag.